# Foundation.css breaks mapquest api

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation, mapquest

Here's the problem.  The mapquest map won't show up with foundation.css present.  Comment it out, and the map displays fine.  I don't know what css rule is causing this, but I looked around and couldn't seem to find it.  Here's a link to the problem

http://jsbin.com/kekuziwido/2/edit?html,output

Comment: Are you using the whole `foundation.css` file or compiling a custom `.css` from the Foundation `.scss` files?

Comment: whole foundation.css

Comment: demo uses relative path to css... doesn't represent problem since path is invalid. Should be fairly easy to inspect in browser console css inspector to find issue if there was a valid replica of problem

Comment: Yeah, the JSBin demo works fine for me.

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot to update the link.  Visit the link now and you should see the problem.

Comment: I replicated the problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/qkcqsLmh/) too. Removing `foundation.css` fixes the problem, I'm looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

Foundation is adding a `max-width` to images. The solution is to overwrite this with:

```
#map img {
  max-width: none !important;
```

}

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/qkcqsLmh/).

Comment: Works great too.  I think the official foundation way is to add the map_canvas class which does the same thing.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I opened an issue in the Foundation repo to add an exception for MapQuest maps. There's already an exception for Google maps, so MapQuest should be added.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix: add class `map_canvas` to the div you are using as a map.  They do some stuff to the images in foundation, and it messes up map display.  They have the corrected info in the map_canvas class